# No unsigned apk when trying to run release apk?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-android

Running this command:

```
ionic cordova run --release --prod --device android -- --nosave
```

I get the error:

```
[native-run] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk'
```

I don't have an unsigned apk, but I do have an app-release.apk at the same path. How can I get the existing signed one used?

I'm on ionic 5.4.16, cordova 10.0.0, and cordova-android 8.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an [ionic-cli bug](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/4374), updating to the latest ionic-cli fixed it for me.